# mocha chai test case does not terminate automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have written following test cases on `mocha-chai` and it works fine and shows the all results passed successfully. But it does not terminate the execution after successfully passed all 6 test cases. I don't know what is the reason that why my test case does not terminate automatically, I need to click CTRL+C to terminate the test case.

I don't know what is the reason test has been successfully passed but does not terminate. I have also written done() at the end of the test case but still it doesn't work

I have used PostgreSQL as database and NodeJS as backend server.

> test.js

```
const { colors } = require('mocha/lib/reporters/base');

colors.pass = 32;
const { describe, it } = require('mocha');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const request = require('superagent');
const should = require('should');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

const envPath = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: envPath });

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db/models');

// Test that server is running or not
describe('Unit tests for add user', () => {
    // Gateway api test case and it's works fine
});

// Read the test cases stored from database and stored in an array
describe('Test Cases', () => {
    // Read the test cases from database
});

// Test case to write test data in csv and upload the csv and insert user information in csv

describe('Process data user csv', () => {    

    it('create user csv to write data in csv', done => {
        // Create user csv from test data and it's passed and successfully completed it
    });

    it('Upload user csv and insert the user in the database with accurate data', done => {
        // Upload user csv and insert user information from csv and it's passed and successfully completed it
    });

    it('verify user information from user table', done => {
        // This method verifies the user data stored user table, which has inserted in test case.
        // Sequlieze query which fetch the user information 

        TestService.executeQuery(
            dbQuery.qGetUserDetails,
            {
            email: arrTestCases[0].expected_result.email,
            },
            'select'
        )
        .then(data => {
            should(data[0].email).equal(arrTestCases[0].expected_result.email);
            done();
        });        
    });
  });
});
```

> app.query.js

```
/**
 * @description default queries
 */
module.exports = {
  qGetUserDetails: `select * from "Users" where email = :email and is_active = true and is_deleted = false`,
};
```

> Test.service.js

```
/**
 * @class TestService
 */
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db/models');

module.exports = class TestService {

  /**
   * @static execute query
   * @param {*} query
   * @param {*} replacements
   * @param {*} operation
   * @memberof TestService
   */
  static executeQuery(query, replacements, operation) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let queryType;
      if (operation === 'insert') {
        queryType = Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT;
      } else if (operation === 'update') {
        queryType = Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE;
      } else if (operation === 'select') {
        queryType = Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT;
      } else if (operation === 'delete') {
        queryType = Sequelize.QueryTypes.DELETE;
      } else {
        queryType = Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT;
      }
      return db.sequelize
        .query(query, { replacements, type: queryType, raw: true })
        .then(data => resolve(data))
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Is it just this test suite? I've had problems with terminals such as mintty not getting the exit code from test runners.

Comment: Did you run mocha with the --exit option?

Comment: I had some issues in the past with something similar, and fixed it buy avoiding the use of arrow functions in the test suites. Somewhere in the documentation I read that mocha and arrow functions (when using asynchronous functions) don't play well. You should try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know what is the reason test has been successfully passed but does not terminate.

You're not closing your database handle when all tests have been run, which means that Node.js doesn't know that you're done.

You can add a root-level `after` hook to close it:

```
after(() => {
  sequelize.close();
});
```

Comment: Thank you robertkelp, it's working. But I am not still understand that, connection is not closed only the reason it does not terminate. Because in any other test case I did not close the connection. Only the difference is that in this test case I do the manually querying.

Comment: We have micro-service architecture and in all the test case it is calling an api to get the data so I did not face any issue. When I add this querying code to get the data from database for comparison, it creates an issue of termination of test cases. All code and logic of test case was work fine but just issue was test terminate does not terminate properly.

Comment: you gave me an answer and it's working to me as well but is it only the reason that is why test case does not automatically terminate after passed. Because we have create "pre-push" in package.json where it first pass the test case and then only it allows to push the code on github. So do you think this is only the reason of terminal hangup, if any possible reason is there then it's appreciated to guide me.

Comment: As with most programming languages: you should clean up all the resources (database connections, timers, opened files) when you're done. Mocha won't do that for you. Because of the still-open database connection, Node.js assumes that "something" might still happen, and won't exit the process. And Mocha won't force-exit the process when all test cases have run, either (because again, it assumes that because of the open database handle, you're not done yet).